# How to create a regular expression to match specific substrings inside brackets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In my Ruby on Rails app I need a regex that accepts the following values:

- `{DD}`
- `{MM}`
- `{YY}`
- `{NN}`
- `{NNN}`
- `{NNNN}`
- `{NNNNN}`
- `{NNNNNN}`
- upper and lowercase letters
- the special characters `-`, `_`, `.` and `#`

I am still new to regular expressions and I came up with this:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z._}{#-]*\z/
```

This works pretty well already, however it also matches strings that should not be allowed such as:

`}FOO` or `{YYY}`

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you mean the literal letters `DD`, `MM`, `NNNNNN`? Why is `{YYY}` not allowed if you say "upper and lowercase letters" are allowed?

Comment: Within rounded brackets only the above mentioned values should be allowed. Outside the rounded brackets, the four special characters and all letters are allowed. I am not even sure if that can be done using Regex.

Comment: Well, try [`/\A(?:\{(?:DD|MM|YY|N{2,6})\}|[A-Za-z_.#-])*\z/`](http://rubular.com/r/4yWHJl9UNn)

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly! Thanks a lot. Just one n00b question: What does the `?:` stand for?

Comment: It is a non-capturing group that does not create submatches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/\A(?:\{(?:DD|MM|YY|N{2,6})\}|[A-Za-z_.#-])*\z/
```

See [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/4yWHJl9UNn)

- `\A`  - start of string anchor
- `(?:\{(?:DD|MM|YY|N{2,6})\}|[A-Za-z_.#-])*` - a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) (`(?:...)` that only groups *sequences* of atoms and does not create submatches/subcaptures) zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\{(?:DD|MM|YY|N{2,6})\}` - a `{` then either `DD`, or `MM`, `YY`, 2 to 6`N` followed with `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Za-z_.#-]` - 1 char from the set (ASCII letter, `_`, `.`, `#` or `-`)
- `\z` - end of string.